# Es posible hacer una conexión de rails con una base de datos sql server montada en una maquina virtual

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Estoy desarrollando en ubuntu y necesito usar una base de datos sql server, es posible hacer la conexión si instalo sql server en una maquina virtual

Answer (score 0):

sí es posible, asegúrate que ambas máquinas compartan la misma red y que tengas el **driver** del SQL Server instalado -> http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: ese driver debo de instalarlo en ubuntu? o en la maquina virtual?

Comment: desde el ubuntu